# PostGIS ST_PointInsideCircle radius units config

Tags: postgis, radius

I have a table with a lat and  a long float columns and I'm trying to use the ST_PointInsideCircle
PostGIS method which is working but the radius I enter is not in the correct units.
I'm trying to config the radius to be in meters, all of the configuration queries I saw with setting a different SRID was for tables with geom point var columns .
I tried running something like this query but it does not work for me the units are still probably in feet or degrees
for example

```
SELECT * 
FROM box nbe 
WHERE ST_PointInsideCircle(ST_Transform(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude),3857), -91.973998, 29.978479, 1000)
```

those are example coordinates they are random

Comment: Distance properties are useless in Web Mercator, since distance is always wrong in that projection. And you seem to be mapping 100 meters off the origin of Web Mercator (Null Island).

Comment: Have a look at `ST_DWithin` with geographies instead

Comment: i tried using the ST_DWithin function but the last argument aka the distance still not seems to be in meters how can i configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `st_dwithin` instead.  Geometry in a geographic coordinate system is using degrees as the units, which is why your 1000 is not working.  Since you want to use meters, cast the geometry to geography, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM box nbe 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude,3857),4326)::geography, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-91.973998, 29.978479),4326)::geography, 1000)
```

If `nbe.longitude / nbe.latitude` are already srid 4326 (WGS 84) then you would do this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM box nbe 
WHERE ST_DWithin(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude,4326)::geography, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-91.973998, 29.978479),4326)::geography, 1000)
```

Regarding casting, according to the docs

> The CAST syntax conforms to SQL; the syntax with :: is historical PostgreSQL usage.

Cast to geography using cast syntax:

```
st_dwithin(cast(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude,4326) as geography),cast(st_point(-91.973998, 29.978479, 4326) as geography),1000)
```

Comment: i get this error when trying to execute that line
" Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography"

Comment: i think the problem is that my lat and long are just float8 values they are not a geom value is there a way that could still work around with that?

Comment: Oh that's my mistake.  I forget that 3857 is a projected coordinate system.  Change that to 4326 in your `st_transform(st_point(...),4326)`.  Also, if you know that the lat/lon are using 3857, do this instead: `st_transform(st_point(nbe.longitude, nbe.latitude, 3857),4326)`

Comment: i tried to work with the "::geography" it worked when i run the query directly into the postgres server but im having troublle when trying to compile the query on spring query
but st_distancesphere method seems to work too is it ok? i red on the docs that is pretty much the same

Comment: `st_distancespheroid` could also work.  It's slower than `st_distancesphere` but is more accurate.  You would have to use either function like this `where st_distancesphere(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude,4326),st_point(-91.973998, 29.978479, 4326)) <= 1000`

Comment: Spring probably doesn't like the `::` casting notation.  You can also try this `st_dwithin(cast(st_point(nbe.longitude,nbe.latitude,4326) as geography),cast(st_point(-91.973998, 29.978479, 4326) as geography),1000)`

Comment: thanks a lot! il try the casting option too